# Python math.pow() losing calculation percision

Tags: python, precision

My code:

```
import math

def calculate(operator, firstValue, secondValue):
    if operator == '^':
        toReturn = math.pow(firstValue, secondValue)
    . . .
    return toReturn

. . . 
new = calculate('^', 19, 19)
print('   is ' + str(new))
workingStack.append(int(new))
print('New stack is ' + str(workingStack))
```

The results are

```
"   is 1.9784196556603136e+24" 
New stack is [16, 14, 1978419655660313627328512]
```

which is fine for the formatted string, but when I actually use the variable, it shows it's losing the precision of the number, as you can see it calculates math.pow(19, 19) as 1978419655660313627328512, but it should be   1978419655660313589123979.

Here is a better way to compare them

- 1978419655660313627328512   <- Calculated value
- 1978419655660313589123979   <- True value

You can see the error occurs where the scientific notation loses the precision in the printed results above. I need to be able to use the true value of the variable in other calculations.

I have read many things about Python 3 automatically converting int to bignum, but bignum doesn't seem to be enough. I tried 19 ** 19 too. It calculates at the same wrong number.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What Python version are you using? I'm using Python 3.5 and 19 ** 19 gives the correct value. For math.pow() I believe it gives back a float even if you pass it two integer values which is why you're losing precision with large numbers.

Comment: Stop using `math.pow`. The `math` module provides access to C standard library functions for working with floating-point numbers; if you want integer arithmetic, the `math` module is not what you're looking for.

Comment: Change `math.pow(firstValue, secondValue)` to `firstValue ** secondValue`.  `math.pow()` forces its arguments to floats.  `**` does not.

Comment: See the comment I made below. I did try **.

Python 3.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`math.pow` does a floating point calculation with finite precision, use the power-operator instead:

```
def calculate(operator, firstValue, secondValue):
    if operator == '^':
        toReturn = firstValue ** secondValue
    return toReturn
```

Comment: The second to last paragraph says I did try ** and it isn't working either.

But if that is the best solution, could something else be wrong?

Comment: @LindsaySpencer: you must have done something else wrong, because `**` works. You should post a minimal example, that shows, that `**` does not work.

Comment: So ** turned out to be the correct method, but I don't know why it didn't work correctly. I have provided all the relevant example code needed. I came back to it after letting it sit for a week or so and it worked correctly. I don't know what changed--nothing in the code did--but it's not worth investigating. Thank you.

Comment: @Daniel this does not work in Python 2.7. I am still looking for a solution.

Comment: @AlexF: it does: `19**19` gives `1978419655660313589123979L` in Python2.7. Ask a new question, if you want a specific answer to your problem.

Comment: Dear @Daniel, please kindly answer this very specific question:
Why does the 9999999999999999 ** (1 / 16) print 10.0??

Comment: To do integer calculation, both operands have to be integers, `1/16 = 0.0625` is a float.